# Transform stateless function to stateful one

Tags: haskell

I am currently writing a compiler in Haskell as a toy project and I have a function that does a stateful transformation with the signature:

```hs
transform :: (Exp -> m Exp) -> Exp -> m Exp
```

This allows me to implement the following types of operations on top of it:

- Accumulate results, e.g. get a list of functions that are called inside an expression.
- Do transformations that can return errors, e.g. type annotation that either returns an AST with types or with an error describing type problems.
- transformations that depend on previously done transformations, e.g. deduplicating variable names when generating test input.
- I hope it will also allow me to do stateless computations in an elegant way.

But somehow, even though this must be really easy, I am stuck on creating a stateless map function based upon the aforementioned transform method that has the following signature:

```
map :: (Exp -> Exp) -> Exp -> Exp
```

I would prefer not to have the same logic on how to traverse the children in map again but really implement it on top of transform.

Comment: What is `m` in your `transform` method?  Is it an arbitrary monad?  Could you just use the `Identity` monad?

Comment: If you really mean `transform :: Monad m => (Exp -> m Exp) -> Exp -> m Exp`, then you can instantiate `m` with `Identity` and get your `map`.

Comment: Yes, m is an arbitrary monad, so I can choose it for the implementation of the map function. But how exactly would I do that? Sorry, it is probably really obvious, but I am somehow confused because I probably thought too long about it already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that is the actual type of `transform`, then you should be able to do something like this:

```
Control.Monad.Identity> :t transform
transform :: (Exp -> m Exp) -> Exp -> m Exp
Control.Monad.Identity> :t \f -> runIdentity . transform (Identity . f)
\f -> runIdentity . transform (Identity . f)
  :: (Exp -> Exp) -> Exp -> Exp
```

However, it's possible that you have other constraints on `m` that you haven't written in the question that may rule out `Identity`.

Comment: No, there are no constraints on m. After all, I wrote my transform operation in this way in order to support different kinds of monads. Thanks a lot. The key part that I didn't see was how to "take it out" of the monad again. But runIdentity solves this, so thanks for that!